# Reset Tesseract-OCR Variable

Tags: c++, tesseract

How can I reset tesseract-ocr's variables?

After using:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI* api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
.
.
.
api->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
```

how do you reset it to recognize everything or back to defaul?
I tried `api->Clear()` and `api->ClearAdaptiveClassifier();`

No difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
api->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "");
```

Comment: I tried this. Throws an error or gives an access violation error.